# Detecting handover failure in Blackberry

Tags: java, blackberry

I am using the `PhoneListener` class to detect when calls fail and do something according to the reason of the failure. The class includes some static variables in the form of `PhoneListener.CALL_ERROR_DUE_TO_FADING`. I also need to detect errors due to handover failure but unfortunately I was not able to find anything for this case. Does anyone have an idea how to check for this specific situation ?

Comment: Do you mean InterRAT handover failure? (eg UMTS <-> GSM)

Comment: Yes but I need to detect all kinds of handover failure not just that one.

Comment: I'm not a Blackberry expert, but I am not aware of another similar interface that will give you such detailed low level information.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what exactly you want to detect, but have a look at these classes:

[RadioStatusListener](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/RadioStatusListener.html) (register it by calling `Application.getApplication().addRadioListner`)

[CoverageStatusListener](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/CoverageStatusListener.html) (register it by calling `CoverageInfo.addListener`)

[CoverageStatusListener](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/io/transport/CoverageStatusListener.html) (register it by calling `TransportInfo.addListener`)